# Control a JQC-3F relay with ESP32

Tags: esp32, relay

I have this circuit I build and I have a problem. When I activate/deactivate SW1, I can hear the RLY1 flip on and off which is fine. But when I activate the PIN 13, the RLY2 do not work. When the relay is connected, I can measure 1.1V but when I disconnect the relay, my multimeter show me 3.3V.

Anyone have an idea of what I could do to fix this issue and be able to control my 3V relay with PINS in ESP32?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fy8XIt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: the ESP32 cannot provide enough current to activate a relay ... research `how to drive a relay with a microcontroller`

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't formulated that in that way in Google, I found how to do it, it now work with the usage of a transistor :D

Comment: You should post an answer, as comments get deleted over time.